# How to use `package::function()` inside a package when `function` is an infix operator?

Tags: r, magrittr, infix-operator

According to H. Wickham's book *R Packages*, in the Package Metadata chapter, on how to add a package dependency, Hadley points out good reasons to explicitly refer to external functions using the syntax `package::function()`.

> Adding a package dependency here ensures that it’ll be installed. However, it does not mean that it will be attached along with your package (i.e., library(x)). **The best practice is to explicitly refer to external functions using the syntax package::function()**. This makes it very easy to identify which functions live outside of your package. This is especially useful when you read your code in the future.

From [R Packages | Package metadata](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html#dependencies).

But how to do it when the `function` is an infix operator? For example, it seems I cannot do `1:10 magrittr::"%>%" sqrt`? And adopting a function style here would defy the purpose of using the pipe operator... is it not?

Comment: I know it's going against the current R style "movement" but I'd ask if you really need to use the piping syntax in your package.

Comment: To really need is a bit of a too strong statement :) But it makes the code a lot more pleasant to read...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would be safe just using the import from magrittr there. But if you wanted you could just make sure that your symbol refers to the one you want by doing

```
your_fun <- function(){
  `%>%` <- magrittr::`%>%`
  # now use %>% like you normally would
  # and you can be sure it refers to the magrittr version.
  return(42)
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `return(42)` here?

Comment: well... you know... it's the answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything.

Comment: It would be silly to have a function return anything else. Unless you wanted me to return a picture of a kitty. That would be understandable.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `package::infix` it with the infix syntax, but you can use infix operators with standard syntax. For example:

```
"+"(1, 2)
# [1] 3

Hmisc::"%nin%"(1:3, 2)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with `magrittr` when the package isn't loaded, probably due to its substitution tricks.

```
## what a shame that this beauty doesn't work:
magrittr::"%>%"(1:5, mean)
# Error in pipes[[i]] : subscript out of bounds

library(magrittr)
"%>%"(1:5, mean)
# [1] 3
```

In a package context, I would recommend just importing `magrittr`, or at least importing `"%>%"`.

---

The source you quote is good enough to explain some of the reasoning behind this best practice:

> This makes it very easy to identify which functions live outside of your package. This is especially useful when you read your code in the future.

This doesn't seem to apply in this case. You are unlikely to forget where `%>%` came or to mistakenly think that it is created in your package.